# can't find assembly for pre-written functions

Tags: c, assembly, networking

I am a huge fan of network protocols and libnet, which is why I've been trying to imitate some network protocols that are not included by libnet. Capturing packets, imitating headers etc works so far. Now I need a way to actually write these exact packets to my network card. I've tried libnet_adv_write_rawipv4() and -link(), both won't work. I can't cull the headers with libnet_adv_cull_header() because of the stupid errors and bugs. So I figured, that the problem could be solved with a little assembly: get the assembly code for the actual libnet_build() and libnet_write() call, alter some bytes and voila: raw bytes get written to the network card. So I have written a dummy program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libnet.h>

int main() {
libnet_t *l;


l = libnet_init(LIBNET_RAW4, 0, NULL);


libnet_build_tcp(2000, 450, 0, 1234, TH_SYN, 254, 0, NULL, LIBNET_TCP_H + 5, 
"aaaaa", 5, l, 0);
libnet_build_ipv4(LIBNET_TCP_H + LIBNET_IPV4_H + 5, 0, 1, 0, 64, 6, 0, 
2186848448, 22587584, NULL, 0, l, 0);

libnet_write(l);
return 0;
}
```

Works so far. Now I got the assembly version of the program using

```
gcc -o program program.c -S
```

And this is where the actual problem starts:

```
 .LC0:
 .string    "aaaaa"
 .text
 .globl main
 .type  main, @function
  main:
 .LFB2:
 .cfi_startproc
  pushq %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
subq    $16, %rsp
movl    $0, %edx
movl    $0, %esi
movl    $1, %edi
call    libnet_init
movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
subq    $8, %rsp
pushq   $0
pushq   -8(%rbp)
pushq   $5
pushq   $.LC0
pushq   $25
pushq   $0
pushq   $0
movl    $254, %r9d
movl    $2, %r8d
movl    $1234, %ecx
movl    $0, %edx
movl    $450, %esi
movl    $2000, %edi
call    libnet_build_tcp
addq    $64, %rsp
subq    $8, %rsp
pushq   $0
pushq   -8(%rbp)
pushq   $0
pushq   $0
pushq   $22587584
pushq   $-2108118848
pushq   $0
movl    $6, %r9d
movl    $64, %r8d
movl    $0, %ecx
movl    $1, %edx
movl    $0, %esi
movl    $45, %edi
call    libnet_build_ipv4
addq    $64, %rsp
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    libnet_write
movl    $0, %eax
leave
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
.size   main, .-main
```

See this?

```
call    libnet_build_ipv4
```

I can't copy the assembly code of these build() or write() calls, because all there is is a reference to them. Now, where would I find the assembly code for these pre-written functions included in libnet-functions.h (libnet_build_ipv4(), libnet_build_tcp(), libnet_write()) ?????

Comment: Why not just Google for libnet source code?  It's freely available.  For example: https://fossies.org/dox/libnet-libnet-1.2/

Comment: It's a good idea, but I would still like to know how to read the assembly for the referenced functions. If not for libnet, then for research's sake.

Comment: What do you mean with "read the assembly"? Read the reference manual for the CPU/SoC/MCU you use and work through the code as everyone else had to. And why is this tagged C if you are asing about Assembler?

Comment: huh?  Single-step into it with a debugger (preferably into the 2nd or later call so you don't get lost in the PLT / lazy dynamic loading code), or disassemble the shared library, or set a breakpoint on the library function.  Or use `gcc -static` so all the library code will be part of your executable, if you have a static version of the library.

Comment: @just_a_tiny_fish There is no "the assembly code" for these functions.   Someone (usually your distributor) used a C compiler to translate the library's source code into assembly and assembled it into machine code.  Every C compiler might generate different assembly in each of its versions, so it is hard to say how exactly the code in your copy of the library looks.  Perhaps try disassembling the `libnet.so` shared object in `/usr/lib`, it's where the machine code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB is your friend in situations like this. You don't say anything about what platform you're on, the following example works on Ubuntu, but should work similarly on other distributions.

First, make sure that you have debug-symbols for libnet installed:

```
sudo apt install libnet1-dbg
```

Find out where libnet is installed:

```
~$ dpkg -L libnet1 | grep \.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnet.so.1.7.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnet.so.1
```

Open it (or your own application) with GDB:

```
~$ gdb /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnet.so.1.7.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnet.so.1.7.0...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnet.so.1.7.0...done.
done.
```

Use the `disassemble` command to inspect anything you like:

```
(gdb) disassemble libnet_build_ipv4
Dump of assembler code for function libnet_build_ipv4:
   0x0000000000007d60 <+0>: push   %r15
   0x0000000000007d62 <+2>: push   %r14
   0x0000000000007d64 <+4>: push   %r13
   0x0000000000007d66 <+6>: push   %r12
   0x0000000000007d68 <+8>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000007d69 <+9>: push   %rbx
   0x0000000000007d6a <+10>:    sub    $0x48,%rsp
   0x0000000000007d6e <+14>:    mov    0xa8(%rsp),%rbx
   0x0000000000007d76 <+22>:    mov    %edx,0x8(%rsp)
   0x0000000000007d7a <+26>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000000000007d83 <+35>:    mov    %rax,0x38(%rsp)
   0x0000000000007d88 <+40>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000007d8a <+42>:    mov    %ecx,0x14(%rsp)
   0x0000000000007d8e <+46>:    mov    0x80(%rsp),%r14d
   0x0000000000007d96 <+54>:    test   %rbx,%rbx
   0x0000000000007d99 <+57>:    mov    0x98(%rsp),%r15
   0x0000000000007da1 <+65>:    je     0x810a <libnet_build_ipv4+938>
   0x0000000000007da7 <+71>:    mov    %esi,%r13d
   0x0000000000007daa <+74>:    mov    0xb0(%rsp),%esi
   0x0000000000007db1 <+81>:    mov    %edi,%ebp
   0x0000000000007db3 <+83>:    mov    $0xd,%ecx
   0x0000000000007db8 <+88>:    mov    $0x14,%edx
   0x0000000000007dbd <+93>:    mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0x0000000000007dc0 <+96>:    mov    %r9d,0x1c(%rsp)
   0x0000000000007dc5 <+101>:   mov    %r8d,0x18(%rsp)
   0x0000000000007dca <+106>:   callq  0xea10 <libnet_pblock_probe>
   0x0000000000007dcf <+111>:   test   %rax,%rax
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
Quit
(gdb)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful.

Comment: @just_a_tiny_fish cool! If you feel I've answered your question, please consider marking it as an accepted solution (the green check mark).